# Protocol delegate doesn't call function

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I implemented [side menu from github](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) in my project. I'm trying to add a `protocol` in it. This way when a `cell` gets selected, a function in another class (the main `viewController`) will get called. Here's my code:

`tableView.swift`

```
protocol menuTableViewProtocol {
    func didSelectCell(SelectedCellNumber : Int)
}

var delegate : menuTableViewProtocol?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.delegate?.didSelectCell(indexPath.row)
}

mainVC.swift

class MainViewController: UIViewController, menuTableViewProtocol {

    ...

    // Conforming to Protocal
    func didSelectCell(SelectedCellNumber: Int)
    {
        switch SelectedCellNumber {
        case 0:
            println("0")

        case 1:
            println("1")

        case 2:
            println("2")

        default:
            println("0101010")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app and select a cell, nothing happens. `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` does get called. (I inserted a `println` and it prints out), but `didSelectCell` (the `protocol function`) doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: In your mainVC have you conformed to this protocol and have you set the instance of tableView delegate as self? Can you show that code as well.

Comment: I edited the question with conforming to  the protocol. I thought I was missing something. I don't have an instance of tableView.swift **in mainVC.swif**, so  therefore can't make the delegate to self. The `tableView` get's created in the navigationController.swift. https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu/blob/master/Example/SwiftSideMenu/MyNavigationController.swift And I only call a method in mainVC.swift. (`toggleSideMenuView`)

Comment: sorry but I don't have much idea about the third party component you are using, but ideally you should have an instance and set the delegate to self in order to have delegates actually work. Or You can look at a notifications as well in case it  suits your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments that you can not set delegate to self and there is no direct relationship between your classes, so you should use NSNotificationCenter instead of protocol and delegate.

//Class A (mainVC.swift)

```
 //Add Observer in init method
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handler:", name: "MyNotification", object: nil)

//Handler
func handler(notif: NSNotification) {
    println("MyNotification was handled");
    println("userInfo: \(notif.userInfo)");
    println("SelectedCellNumber \(notif.userInfo!["selectedCellNumber"])"); //Validate userInfo here. it could be nil

}
```

//Class B (tableView.swift)

```
// Call from any method
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MyNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["selectedCellNumber" : indexPath.row]);
```

for more detail, you can follow some tutorials;

http://derpturkey.com/nsnotificationcenter-with-swift/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I pass `indexPath.row` to `mainVC.swift`?